# GWT GiLead Hibernate IllegalArgumentException while trying to send LightEntity throw wire

Tags: hibernate, gwt, gilead

On my GWT client side, i request a list of LightEntities from the server side. I make some modification on the entities and i try to send them back for saving.

When i make the rpc call it fails with the following exception:

```
[WARN] Exception while dispatching incoming RPC call
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
    at net.sf.gilead.core.beanlib.merge.MergePropertyFilter.propagate(MergePropertyFilter.java:230)
    at net.sf.beanlib.provider.BeanPopulator.doit(BeanPopulator.java:186)
    at net.sf.beanlib.provider.BeanPopulator.processSetterMethod(BeanPopulator.java:172)
    at net.sf.beanlib.provider.BeanPopulator.populate(BeanPopulator.java:269)
    at net.sf.gilead.core.LazyKiller.populate(LazyKiller.java:288)
    at net.sf.gilead.core.LazyKiller.attach(LazyKiller.java:237)
    at net.sf.gilead.core.PersistentBeanManager.mergePojo(PersistentBeanManager.java:554)
    at net.sf.gilead.core.PersistentBeanManager.merge(PersistentBeanManager.java:318)
    at net.sf.gilead.core.PersistentBeanManager.mergeCollection(PersistentBeanManager.java:581)
    at net.sf.gilead.core.PersistentBeanManager.merge(PersistentBeanManager.java:290)
    at net.sf.gilead.gwt.GileadRPCHelper.parseInputParameters(GileadRPCHelper.java:94)
    at net.sf.gilead.gwt.GileadRPCHelper.parseInputParameters(GileadRPCHelper.java:137)
    at net.sf.gilead.gwt.PersistentRemoteService.processCall(PersistentRemoteService.java:172)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:224)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:487)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:362)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:181)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:729)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:405)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.RequestLogHandler.handle(RequestLogHandler.java:49)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:324)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:505)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:843)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:647)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:211)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:380)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:395)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:488)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at net.sf.gilead.core.beanlib.merge.MergePropertyFilter.writePropertyValue(MergePropertyFilter.java:285)
    at net.sf.gilead.core.beanlib.merge.MergePropertyFilter.propagate(MergePropertyFilter.java:179)
```

I am sitting on this error for hours now, thats LazyKiller is killing me, any tips where should i look again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to use Gilead but it's bad that:

1. it is so invasive;
2. it is so hard to configure.

I wrote a small class that converts hibernate proxies to normal java classes and it really helps me.
It is shared as open source there, so you could try:

http://code.google.com/p/dehibernator/

Comment: I will try that out, and if this works i will happily throw out GILEAD, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I could not solve this problem, but i did a little workaround:
I cloned my entities on the client side and then i could send them back to server side.